# How do I apply an icon to two form fields in Angular Material?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I'm using angular material as my design framework. I'm prototyping the form fields for my website, and the form fields have an icon. Selecting the form field changes the color of the icon to indicate that it's been selected.

My question is I have two fields, side-by-side which both correspond to one icon. I have a first and last name field that both point to the same user icon.

When I choose the first name field, the icon turn blue.[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rIau.png)
When I choose the last name field, the icon remains gray. [See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0vsK.png) 
How do  I make it so that the user icon also changes blue with the last name field selected?

```html
<html>
  <head>


 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.8/angular-material.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    
      


</head>

  <body  ng-app="StyleApp">

<div class="group-fields" layout="column" layout-gt-sm="row" layout-md="row">

                            <md-input-container class="md-icon-float" layout="row" flex-gt-sm>
                                <label>First Name</label>
                                <md-icon class="material-icons md-18 color-txt-gray">person</md-icon>
                                <input ng-model="user.firstname">
                            </md-input-container>

                            <md-input-container class="" flex-gt-sm>
                                <label>Last Name</label>
                                <input ng-model="user.lastname">
                            </md-input-container>

                        </div>
    
          <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.8/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script>
            angular.module('StyleApp', ['ngMaterial']);

        </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the HTML, my guess would be you have two `md-input-container` elements and the first one has the icon in it, so that's why it turns blue when you focus on the first input field. You could still achieve what you want, but you have to add the same CSS manually to the icon when you `focus`/`blur` the 2nd input field.

**Edit:** After seeing the code, basically what I've just above. One way to do it would be to use a scope variable, and on the 2nd input field use `ng-focus="focusingLastName = true"`, `ng-blur="focusingLastName = false"` combined with `ng-class` on the `md-icon` element in the 1st container. You'll probably have to create a class and just copy the same CSS that Angular Material would've added by default (I'm fairly certain it's just a simple `color` rule).